# How to bind DataGridTextColumn to a method in Object to which it is binded in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a more C# specific query as I come from Java Background.

I have a WinUi3 project with DataGrid Binded to a ObservableCollection of Objects (Players). And the ObservableCollection of Objects is declared in the current Window code (Teams) and data is fetched from a sqlite3 database.

`public ObservableCollection<Player> AllPlayersInAllPlayersGrid = new ObservableCollection<Player>();`

DataGrid is Binded to the above ObservableCollection :

`<controls:DataGrid x:Name="allPlayersGrid" ItemsSource="{x:Bind AllPlayersInAllPlayersGrid}"`

and individual DataGridTextColumn binded to Player variable as follows:

`<controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="LR" FontSize="10" Binding="{Binding BATHAND}" />`

And variable BATHAND in Player class:

```
public string BATHAND { get; set; }
```

Now what I want to is for some values, which are "NA" in the column, I just want to display them as blank, so I created method:

```
public string GetBATHAND ()
 {
  if (BATHAND.Equals("NA"))
  return "";
  else
  return BATHAND;
 }
```

My issues are :

1. How do I bind this method to DataGridTextColumn because when I do

```
Binding="{Binding GetBATHAND}"
```

it does not recognize the method.

2. Tried overriding Getter method, but it says Setter needs to be changed too so I tried:

```
 public string BATHAND { get => GetBATHAND(); set => SetBATHAND(value); }

        private void SetBATHAND(string value)
        {
            this.BATHAND = value;
        }
```

But I am getting `System.StackOverflowException`for the above.

What is the right way to do it in C# if I have to override the Getter method only ? I did see some examples where I can declare another class as Abstract and make the Player class inherit it, but is there a simpler way like in Java we can just create our own logic when getting variable value.

Or What is the best solution here to bind DataGridTextColumn to have conditional display of values ?

Thank you and pardon my C# ignorance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ValueConverter` for this:

```cs
public class NAToEmptyStringValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return value is string stringValue && stringValue != "N/A"
            ? stringValue
            : string.Empty;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:NAToEmptyStringValueConverter x:Key="NAToEmptyStringValueConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Header="LR"
    FontSize="10"
    Binding="{Binding BATHAND,  Converter={StaticResource NAToEmptyStringValueConverter}}" />
```

You can go further and pass the value you want to be empty as `ConverterParameter`:

```cs
public class ToEmptyStringValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return
            value is string stringValue &&
            parameter is string stringParameter &&
            stringValue != stringParameter
                ? stringValue
                : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ToEmptyStringValueConverter x:Key="ToEmptyStringValueConverter"/>
</Page.Resources>
```

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Header="LR"
    FontSize="10"
    Binding="{Binding BATHAND,  Converter={StaticResource ToEmptyStringValueConverter}, ConverterParameter='N/A'}" />
```

No need to go this far but just to show you how you can bind values to `ValueConverters`:

```cs
public class ToEmptyStringValueConverter : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
{
    public string ValueToBeEmpty
    {
        get => (string)GetValue(ValueToBeEmptyProperty);
        set => SetValue(ValueToBeEmptyProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueToBeEmptyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(ValueToBeEmpty),
        typeof(string),
        typeof(ToEmptyStringValueConverter),
        new PropertyMetadata(default));

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return
            value is string stringValue &&
            stringValue != ValueToBeEmpty
                ? stringValue
                : string.Empty;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <local:ToEmptyStringValueConverter x:Key="NAToEmptyStringValueConverter" ValueToBeEmpty={x:Bind SomeValue}/>
</Page.Resources>
```

```xml
<controls:DataGridTextColumn
    Header="LR"
    FontSize="10"
    Binding="{Binding BATHAND,  Converter={StaticResource NAToEmptyStringValueConverter}}" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of declaring a GetBATHAND() method, use the getter of the BATHAND property:

```
private string _bathand = "";

public string BATHAND 
{ 
  get
  {
    if (_bathand.Equals("NA"))
      return "";
    else
      return _bathand;
  }
}
```

and let the DataGridTextColumn 's binding as it is to 'BATHAND' property.

If you want to keep your 'BATHAND' property untouched, you can define a secondary property (e.g. BATHAND_DYNAMIC etc.)

I assume, it's obvious that you must initialize _bathand somewhere before.

Comment: Thanks A,B, works perfectly fine. I was worried (again java background) about not seeing setter here, but I guess it is auto implemented. Was difficult in not choosing this answer as accepted as @Andrew Keep Coding response was better suited to my need as I had lots of columns to process. Nevertheless this works brilliant